# How can I convert a String to a Date and then to a different format?

Tags: java, date

Actually I wanted to convert one String to date and then I need to format it in to one another format..

The String I have is

```
 String val="Wed Jan 08 08:49:13 GMT+05:30 2014";
```

To convert it to

```
 2014-01-30 10:14:18  , this format
```

Is it possible to do this I tried some method like

```
       SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

        Calendar cal =   Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1:00"));
          // Date currentLocalTime = ;
            DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:mmss a");
```

But nothing worked

Comment: why not use joda-time?

Comment: Telling us that nothing worked is not helpful. Tell us how and why it didn't work.

Comment: If you have a date string, you need to parse it into a `Date` before you can format it differently.

Comment: Of course it is possible but I don't see how your code is gonna do that. For date parsing I recommend [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), which [parses rather well](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). Anyway, how about writing a JUnit test case or two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format string for parsing doesn't match the example date you have given.

You could try something like the following:

```
    String val = "Wed Jan 08 08:49:13 GMT+05:30 2014";
    DateFormat inFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
    Date date = inFmt.parse(val);
    DateFormat outFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    outFmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1:00"));
    System.out.println(outFmt.format(date));
```

Note the following correspondences in the first two lines:

- Wed -> EEE
- Jan -> MMM
- 08 -> dd
- etc.